# Writing the following set using set builder notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm learning DM and currently stuck on finding the correct set builder for:

*B*={−1, 1/2, −1/3, 1/4, −1/5, 1/6,···}

how do i find the steps? Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s $(-1)^n/n$

Answer (score 1):

The series is of the form (-1)^n * 1/n

Comment: Your answer is ok. But this is not a series, it is a sequence.